# rpm installation failing with aws user data?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, rpm

With normal installation it is successful but with aws ec2 user data it is failing.

When I observed, the rpm, generated from [fpm](https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/v1.13.1/), is having a --before-script prelaunch script, which is not running completely when ran from ec2 userdata section.

How to fix that?

The prelaunch script

```
#!/bin/bash
#echo "Cleaning old environment"
rm -fr ~/.pyenv
rm -fr /root/.pyenv
rm -fr /usr/local/pipx/venvs/myproject
rm -fr /usr/local/python_myproject
#echo "Installing pyenv"

pyenv_release=2.2.5
wget https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/archive/refs/tags/v$pyenv_release.tar.gz -O pyenv-package.tar.gz
tar -xvf pyenv-package.tar.gz
mv pyenv-$pyenv_release /root/.pyenv
rm -rf pyenv-package.tar.gz

export PATH=$(/root/.pyenv/bin/pyenv root)/bin:$(/root/.pyenv/bin/pyenv root)/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:$PATH

python_version=3.9.5
#echo "Installing python: $python_version"

$(pyenv which python-build) $python_version /usr/local/python_myproject/

INSTALL_PATH="/usr/local/lib/project-n"
rm -rf $INSTALL_PATH

export PATH=/usr/local/python_myproject/bin:$PATH
#whereis python3
#python3 --version


if ! python3 -m pip --disable-pip-version-check show pipx 2>&1 | grep -qE '^Version: ([1-9]|0\.1[5-9]|0\.1[0-4][0-9]+|0\.[2-9][0-9]+)'; then
    python3 -m pip --disable-pip-version-check -qqq install --upgrade --user pipx
fi

#echo "pre-inst completed"
```

This already part of rpm, which installs directly in centos,redhat,aws linux 2 directly with yum install -y rpmfilepath.

The above is the prelaunch script.

I am not running it separately.

Pulling it separately and running it, I don't think as a feasible option. It should be automatic through rpm.

output pf /var/log/cloud-init-output.log

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-25-8 log]$ ls
amazon    boot.log-20220512  cloud-init.log         dmesg               lastlog   sa       tallylog
audit     btmp               cloud-init-output.log  grubby_prune_debug  maillog   secure   wtmp
boot.log  chrony             cron                   journal             messages  spooler  yum.log
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-25-8 log]$ cat cloud-init-output.log
cat: cloud-init-output.log: Permission denied
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-25-8 log]$ sudo cat cloud-init-output.log
Cloud-init v. 19.3-45.amzn2 running 'init-local' at Wed, 11 May 2022 20:32:47 +0000. Up 5.33 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 19.3-45.amzn2 running 'init' at Wed, 11 May 2022 20:32:48 +0000. Up 6.41 seconds.
ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +--------+------+----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
ci-info: | Device |  Up  |          Address           |      Mask     | Scope  |     Hw-Address    |
ci-info: +--------+------+----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
ci-info: |  eth0  | True |        172.31.25.8         | 255.255.240.0 | global | 0a:31:08:4a:7c:3f |
ci-info: |  eth0  | True | fe80::831:8ff:fe4a:7c3f/64 |       .       |  link  | 0a:31:08:4a:7c:3f |
ci-info: |   lo   | True |         127.0.0.1          |   255.0.0.0   |  host  |         .         |
ci-info: |   lo   | True |          ::1/128           |       .       |  host  |         .         |
ci-info: +--------+------+----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route IPv4 info++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +-------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: | Route |   Destination   |   Gateway   |     Genmask     | Interface | Flags |
ci-info: +-------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: |   0   |     0.0.0.0     | 172.31.16.1 |     0.0.0.0     |    eth0   |   UG  |
ci-info: |   1   | 169.254.169.254 |   0.0.0.0   | 255.255.255.255 |    eth0   |   UH  |
ci-info: |   2   |   172.31.16.0   |   0.0.0.0   |  255.255.240.0  |    eth0   |   U   |
ci-info: +-------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++Route IPv6 info+++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: | Route | Destination | Gateway | Interface | Flags |
ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: |   9   |  fe80::/64  |    ::   |    eth0   |   U   |
ci-info: |   11  |    local    |    ::   |    eth0   |   U   |
ci-info: |   12  |  multicast  |    ::   |    eth0   |   U   |
ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
May 11 20:32:49 cloud-init[2925]: __init__.py[WARNING]: Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata: 'yum -y install https://s...'
Cloud-init v. 19.3-45.amzn2 running 'modules:config' at Wed, 11 May 2022 20:32:50 +0000. Up 8.52 seconds.
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 3173.
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  31 M RSS (324 MB VSZ)
    Started: Wed May 11 20:32:49 2022 - 00:02 ago
    State  : Sleeping, pid: 3173
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  31 M RSS (324 MB VSZ)
    Started: Wed May 11 20:32:49 2022 - 00:04 ago
    State  : Sleeping, pid: 3173
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  33 M RSS (324 MB VSZ)
    Started: Wed May 11 20:32:49 2022 - 00:06 ago
    State  : Running, pid: 3173
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  86 M RSS (380 MB VSZ)
    Started: Wed May 11 20:32:49 2022 - 00:08 ago
    State  : Running, pid: 3173
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  90 M RSS (383 MB VSZ)
    Started: Wed May 11 20:32:49 2022 - 00:10 ago
    State  : Running, pid: 3173
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory : 163 M RSS (456 MB VSZ)
    Started: Wed May 11 20:32:49 2022 - 00:12 ago
    State  : Running, pid: 3173
 --> iproute-5.10.0-2.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 from installed removed (updateinfo)
 --> curl-7.79.1-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 from installed removed (updateinfo)
 --> curl-7.79.1-2.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 from amzn2-core removed (updateinfo)
 --> libcurl-7.79.1-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 from installed removed (updateinfo)
 --> libcurl-7.79.1-2.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 from amzn2-core removed (updateinfo)
 --> kernel-tools-5.10.109-104.500.amzn2.x86_64 from installed removed (updateinfo)
 --> kernel-tools-5.10.112-108.499.amzn2.x86_64 from amzn2extra-kernel-5.10 removed (updateinfo)
 --> iproute-5.10.0-2.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 from amzn2extra-kernel-5.10 removed (updateinfo)
No packages needed for security; 4 packages available
Resolving Dependencies
Cloud-init v. 19.3-45.amzn2 running 'modules:final' at Wed, 11 May 2022 20:33:05 +0000. Up 23.49 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 19.3-45.amzn2 finished at Wed, 11 May 2022 20:33:05 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 23.74 seconds
```

I ran the commands directly in userdata now and saw, it is getting stuck at below command.

```
/root/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/bin/python-build $python_version /usr/local/python_projectn/
```

If I run later once login, it is working.
But with userdata of aws, it is getting stuck at installing the python and stopping there.

```
Downloading Python-3.9.5.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.5/Python-3.9.5.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.9.5...
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting from this script?

Comment: INSTALL_PATH="/usr/local/lib/project-n"
rm -rf $INSTALL_PATH what is the sense of this part..? Anyhow ,I would suggest put this all in a script and make it log. Check this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-log-user-data/

Comment: why would a variable value, even if not used, will cause an issue here?

Comment: I don't think your script is being executed. By default, user data is run once when the system boots up the first time but you can change this behaviour https://aws.amazon.com/it/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/. Nobody said a variable which is not being used caused this issue...